# Karate API Testing - Sorting Validation Scenario

Tags: karate

I have a request which produces below response:

```
{
"totalRows": 10,
"colDefs": [
    {
        "entityAttributeId": "somestring",
        "headerName": "somestring",
        "field": "someNumber",
        "entityPath": "",
        "entityId": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "entityAttributeId": "somestring",
        "headerName": "somestring",
        "field": "someNumber",
        "entityPath": "somestring",
        "entityId": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "entityAttributeId": "somestring",
        "headerName": "somestring",
        "field": "1",
        "entityPath": "",
        "entityId": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "entityAttributeId": "somestring",
        "headerName": "somestring",
        "field": "3",
        "entityPath": "somestring",
        "entityId": "somestring"
    }
],
"rowData": [
    {
        "1": "",
        "2": "s",
        "3": "1939EX",
        "4": "",
        "rowMeta": {
            "text/inthisform": {
                "someid": "1939EX"
            },
            "somestring": {
                "somestring": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "",
        "2": ",
        "3": "1939A2",
        "4": "",
        "rowMeta": {
            "text/inthisform": {
                "someid": "1939A2"
            },
            "somestring": {
                "somestring": "somevalue"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "",
        "2": "",
        "3": "1939A1",
        "4": "",
        "rowMeta": {
            "text/inthisform": {
                "someid": "1939A1"
            },
            "somestring": {
                "somevalue": "value"
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "1": "",
        "2": "",
        "3": "193901",
        "4": "",
        "rowMeta": {
            "sometext/inthisform": {
                "somevalue": "193901"
            },
            "somevalue": {
                "somevalue": "value"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Now I need to apply sorting feature over this field values."sometext/inthisform": {
                    "somevalue": "193901"
                },
In Java, I can easily do this by storing this response an array and sort it and later compare it by my sort feature response.

With Karate, I have no clue, how to go forward.

I am trying below option:
And def temp =  ListDataSet_Response.rowMeta.rowData[*].3

or 
And def temp =  ListDataSet_Response.rowMeta.sometext/inthisform.somevalue

to store the arraylist values. As Karate does not give any compilation or any kind of error information, I am not sure how to proceed in this cases?

Summary: I want to store the values of a field into an array and want to apply sort into it. After applying sort, I want to compare this new sorted array with my features sorted array response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by this way:

1. Store the JSONArray values with the help of jsonpath:

   And def temp = $ListDataSet_Response.rowData[*].3
2. Call the sort functions directly in the feature file itself.

These lines added in **feature file** **Background**:

```
* def ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList')
* def Collections = Java.type('java.util.Collections')
```

Added these line for Sorting in Ascending order:Created list and added values to this temp variable(stored response) into that list.Later,Applied sorting over that list.

```
And def listAsAscending = new ArrayList()
* eval for(var i = 0; i < sometextid.length; i++) listAsAscending.add(sometextid[i])
* eval Collections.sort(listAsAscending, java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
* print listAsAscending
```

Similarly for Descending order:

```
And def listAsDescending = new ArrayList()
* eval for(var i = 0; i < sometextid.length; i++) listAsDescending.add(sometextid[i])
* eval Collections.sort(listAsDescending, Collections.reverseOrder())
* print listAsDescending
```

To compare the list, with my sort API response later:

```
* match sortedTemp == listAsAscending
* match sortedTemp == listAsDescending
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this example that even involves a case-insensitive sort. It is easy to dive into Java from Karate, especially for a complex use-case like this:

```
Scenario: case-insensitive sort
    * def ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList')
    * def Collections = Java.type('java.util.Collections')

    * def json = [{ v: 'C' }, { v: 'b' }, { v: 'A' }]
    * def actual = $json[*].v
    * match actual == ['C', 'b', 'A']
    * def list = new ArrayList()
    * eval for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) list.add(actual[i])
    * match list == ['C', 'b', 'A']
    * eval Collections.sort(list, java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
    * match list == ['A', 'b', 'C']
```

Since your example is too complex, I can't provide a specific answer, kindly refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

For a cleaner way to express the above code, refer the actual example, where you can move some of the code into JS: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/sort-array.feature

EDIT: Karate 1.0 introduces a native `karate.sort()` API, search for it in the docs.

Comment: I am able to get the  array now with these lines in Karate:  And def temp =  $ListDataSet_Response.rowData[*].3. The out put is :  15:35:49.918 [print] [
  "193902",
  "193903",
  "193961",
  "1939A2",
  "193962",
  "193946",
  "1939EX",
  "193959",
  "1939A1",
  "193901"
] . Now i need to sort this output in Ascending and Descending order. Hope, now it is clear.

Comment: And When I am passing this output [ "193902", "193903", "193961", "1939A2", "193962", "193946", "1939EX", "193959", "1939A1", "193901" ] to my java class where I have written my logic to perform sort,it is throwing this error:  Cannot cast net.minidev.json.JSONArray to [Ljava.lang.Object or can not cast to  [Ljava.lang.String

Comment: So following lines of code sorted the output in Ascending order: And def list = new ArrayList()
   * eval for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) list.add(temp[i])
   * print list
   * eval Collections.sort(list, java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
   * print list
   Now, I need to sort with Descending order as well.  eval Collections.reverseOrder(list, java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER), this line is failing.

Comment: sorry can't understand / read with this kind of info. you can try follow this process or wait for someone else to help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas In karate 1.0, when i try to sort the given response using a key, karate removes duplicate entries after sorting. Is this by design?

Comment: @JitendraSingh quite likely a bug. follow this process please (and better still help us fix it ;) https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Done
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1819