# How to compare each element in two different lists in Karate?

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

Refer https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/#loops

Here

```
* def fun = function(i){ return i * 2 }
* def foo = karate.repeat(5, fun)
* match foo == [1, 1, 1, 6, 8]
```

'foo' when mismatches with the first element, karate stops to match rest of the elements
What can be used here so as to compare all elements of two lists (index wise)
[image]

Comment: yes, karate will stop on the first failure. you are welcome to contribute code to improve karate. that said, maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108755/143475 - and please note that things like `match contains` exist for similar use cases

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks for information ! for now I have handle it using Java code

Comment: @PeterThomas I don't think this question should be marked as duplicate as in the ref link given by you deals with JSON but I what I am trying to do is to match match values in two lists index-wise. match contains won't do that

Comment: please assume that there is no built in way in karate to do that. it is actually possible if you write a loop or if you use `karate.sort()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932601/143475